# In a hibernate maven project, where should I place the hibernate.cfg.xml file? Please tell the proper directory structure

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, spring-boot

I am getting a lot of errors. Sometimes `ClassNotFound` exception or `JAXB` Exception or `Tupulizer` error. How to solve these hibernate errors?.

What is the desired version of Java, Hibernate to use together to avoid all errors?

PS: I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Can't help without any code

Comment: `src/main/resources/(and below) ` is an appropriate place for these (will end up in `target/classes/(and below)`).

Comment: Thank You xerx. I guess first one is the best suited one!